# Async setState and handlers

Tags: reactjs

I am aware that setState calls can be batched and are async. However I couldn't find any information about what's the final boundary for handling the process of setting new state.

I am specifically interested whether another handler code can be invoked before state updates from previous handler are applied.
Is that possible?

Example:

```
1. Render

2. Handler A
  setState(a: 1)

3. Render

4. Handler B
  if this.state.a == 1 // can this get state not updated by Handler1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "handler code"?

Comment: I mean code responding to `onClick`, `onChange` events etc.

Comment: I am not sure why you are going to get the original state in bullet 4? IMO, the `this.state` is for UI only, its batch update policy is good to UI changes. If you want some logic state, create another property, e.g., `this.data` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
componentWillUpdate
```

This is called after other components set state, which will cause your component to render, but before your component's state actually changes, and before your component renders. You can read state in this method but you can't set it. (because the state transition is already underway)

If you want to be able to both read and set state in your component, look at

```
componentWillReceiveProps
```

Details are at http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: No, that's not what I am looking for. I am asking if due to supposed async nature of react handler can second handler get fired before state from first handler is already applied. I don't look for specific API call or lifecycle methods. Just an answer to a question.